# Replace string placeholder value in java (conditions apply)

Tags: java, spring

My question might be little odd. I have below condition in String

```
String condition="((1 || 3) && 4)"; ***//I am fine to add special characters in this condition as well..***
```

In my code, I need to dynamically evaluate expression by replacing number values with `ArrayList.get` as below:

```
boolean result=(someArrayList.get(1).isResult() || someArrayList.get(3).isResult()) && someArrayList.get(4).isResult();
```

My question is that, how can I easily replace numbers (1,3,4) in above condition with `someArrayList.get(1)`... I can write logic to do it, but trying to see if there's any easy API to use it.

Comment: What do you want to edit ? the variable  `condition` or `result` ? and can you give an example of what you want to do ? 
thanks

Comment: @MahmoudHendi Sure, I want to replace condition value like this which should be dynamic condition.replace("1","someArrayList.get(1).isResult()")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `replaceAll`:

```
String condition="((1 || 3) && 4)";
String newCondition = condition.replaceAll("(\\d+)", "someArrayList.get($1).isResult()");
```

[<kbd>Ideone Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/MZO41Z)

```
((someArrayList.get(1).isResult() || someArrayList.get(3).isResult()) && someArrayList.get(4).isResult())
```

Comment: How can I evaluate it as expression? When I try below code it's throwing error                               String condition="((1 || 3) && 4)";
        String newCondition = condition.replaceAll("(\\d+)", "list.get($1).isResult()");
        ExpressionParser parser=new SpelExpressionParser();
        boolean result=(boolean)parser.parseExpression(newCondition).getValue();

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String condition = "((1 || 3) && 4)";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(condition);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(condition);
        int index, fromIndex = 0, upTo;
        while (m.find()) {
            String num = m.group();
            index = sb.indexOf(num, fromIndex);
            upTo = index + num.length();
            sb.replace(index, upTo, "someArrayList.get(" + num + ").isResult()");
            fromIndex = upTo;
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
((someArrayList.get(1).isResult() || someArrayList.get(3).isResult()) && someArrayList.get(4).isResult())
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. But, as I mentioned in question, I am looking for some available API to do this logic.